# MVC 3 Menu Navigation on from _layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm making the transition to MVC 3 and was attempting to create a friendly Menu Interface after the person logs onto the site. I stumbled across this article which suits what I need:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1583036.aspx/1

The third code sample is marvelous example of how I can dynamically build a menu interface. It contains the menu and the sub menu. The article creates a controller and a menu model, but I've struggled to get it implemented into Razor - has anyone successfully tried this route in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `<%=` with `@`:

```
@Html.MenuItem("Web Users", "Index", "Home")
```

In order to bring the MenuItem custom helper into scope for your Razor views make sure to reference it's namespace inside the `<namespaces>` tag of `~/Views/web.config` (and not `~/web.config`):

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="SomeNamespace.Containing.The.Helper.Class" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Hi - I just did that. Now, I added the following code in the _Layout.cshtml page:

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model.MainMenuItems)
                    { 

                         <li @if (item.Text == Model.CurrentMainMenuItem) { id="menuitemselected"; } >
                            Html.ActionLink(item.Text, item.Action, item.Controller)
                         </li>

                     }

                </ul>
              </div>`

Comment: @dawriter, this code is totally broken and doesn't resemble Razor.

Comment: My apologies - the above code - I added it to the _Layout.cshtml page to generate the menu. however, it is stalling at the variable -  { id="menuitemselected"; } - I konw menuitemselected is part of the class but I'm stumped to the variable 'id'.

Comment: @dawriter, you have a trailing `;` that you should remove.

Comment: { id="menuitemselected" } - the trailing ; was removed, however it is still expecting it and says that id does not exist in the current context...